# Subfigure in memoir

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, memoir, subfloats

I am using `pgfplots` to draw plots in `memoir`. I have a problem for subfigure plots.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfigure{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major,xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=0.5]
\addplot[color=black] coordinates {
(0,0.2)
(0.5,0.2)
(1,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfigure{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major,xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=0.5]
\addplot[color=black] coordinates {
(0,0.5)
(1,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But the code cannot be compiled successfully. Is there anyone know how to modify the code?

Answer (score 5):

As a document class, [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides the functionality for creating subfloats. As such, using packages that also provide this functionality might cause problems (in general). Here's how you could obtain the desired result by using the interface provided by `memoir`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{pgfplots,pgf}
\newsubfloat{figure}% Create subfloat in figure environment

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subbottom[First]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[grid=major,xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=0.5]
      \addplot[color=black] coordinates {
        (0,0.2)
        (0.5,0.2)
        (1,0)
      };
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
  \subbottom[Second]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[grid=major,xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=0.5]
      \addplot[color=black] coordinates {
        (0,0.5)
        (1,0)
      };
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`\newsubfloat{<fenv>}` creates the appropriate counters/macros for allows subfloats inside `<fenv>`. `\subbottom`/`\subtop` are then used to contain the subfloat with a caption at the bottom/top.

For more detail, read sections **10.3 Multiple floats** (p 177) and **10.9 Subcaptions** (p 194) or the [`memoir` user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The counters `\c@lofdepth` and `\c@lotdepth` are defined by `subfigure` but already defined by `memoir`, which leads to an error. You can fix it by undefining them before loading `subfigure`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
 ...
\makeatletter
\let\c@lofdepth\relax
\let\c@lotdepth\relax
\makeatother
\usepackage{subfigure}
```

By the way, I recommend to use the newer [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package instead, which is from the same author, since `subfigure` is obsolete. Another very good package for subfigures is [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption).